# Textbox for page number

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just started learning asp.net, I want to put a textbox in my gridview control to let the user input whichever page the user wanna go instead of click First/Prev/Next/Last buttons.

Within the gridview control pagersetting mode, I can't find an option to create this kind of function. Is there a way to do this in ASP.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Visual Studio -> File -> New Project -> Web -> **ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities WebApplication**

In solution explorer expand Dynamic Data -> Content folder

There is an awesome user control called GridViewPager.ascx:

[image]

Add it to your project and specify it as the PagerTemplate in the GridView:

```
<PagerTemplate>
   <asp:GridViewPager runat="server" />
</PagerTemplate>
```

You may need to tweak the user control slightly to work for your specific project but this should give you a good start

Comment: Currently, I am using VS2008, I can't find ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities WebApplication under Web or anywhere, so I don't really get this.

Comment: It's 2013 why are you using VS 2008?! Dynamic data web applications have been implemented from .NET 3.5 onwards. You could try installing .NET 3.5 or upgrade your Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

Its called paging. [This](http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-paging.htm) will show you how to implement paging. I know its not ASP.NET but the C# code the methods are the same. As they explain you need to use a data adapter to create the pages the viewer will see.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: It is something similar to this paging setting, but I want to create a textbox that can allow the user to input a number. Then, it will redirect to the number of the page. Thanks!

Comment: @DoesItMatter Yeah, look at the code, you could easily implement that based on their code.