# ASP.net DataPager rendering First and Last Links as page numbers

Tags: asp.net, datapager

I want to create a pager in the format

```
[Prev][1] ... [8 (current)] ... [25(last)] [Next]
```

The bit I'm having trouble is the first and last links. I've tried using  "`NextPreviousPagerField`" controls and setting `ShowFirstPageButton/ShowLastPageButton` to true. Unfortunately, when I do this, the first and last links render with text "`First`" and "`Last`". What I would like is for them to render as "1" and whatever the final pagenumber is.

How do I create this?

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668332/textbox-for-page-number/14671299#14671299

Comment: Unfortunately, that article did not address the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using TemplatePagerFields: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatepagerfield.aspx